# JavaScript Virtualkeyboard

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to make a virtual keyboard using JavaScript. When I am going to click on the key, a `div` is created but the text is not coming from the keybutton.

With the help of `alert(targ.childNodes[0].textContent);` I am able to show the characters on  the alert, but how to insert it into the div?

Comment: How are you creating the div and how are you trying to set its contents?

Comment: do you want to append text to the div? if so: document.getElementById('textContent').innerHTML += valueToAppend. BTW, if you decide to use jquery: http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/

Comment: I created the div using document.createElement then i assigned an id to it as div.id="popup" now i want the key which i am pressing should display at the div using javascript only

Comment: i mean the the key text should be displayed on the div

Comment: For ex if i am pressing "a" button then at the div it should display a

Comment: With the help of that alert i am able to show the key characters in the alertbox but how to show it in the div???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the String ina property means, onclick function get the string and add that string to password property.

```
function getCharText(text){

    if(capsEnable == 1)
        text = text.toUpperCase();      
    var textString= "";
    var textValue = document.forms[0].password.value;
    if(textValue != '')
            textString = textValue;
    if(document.forms[0].enableKeyboard.checked == true){       
        if(text == "bs" || text == "BS")    
            textString = textString.substring(0, textString.length-1);  
        else if(text == "ca" || text == "CA")   
            textString = "";
        else if(text == "sl" || text == "SL")   
            textString = textString + "\\";
        else if(text == "dq" || text == "DQ")   
            textString = textString + "\"";
        else if(text == "sq" || text == "SQ")   
            textString = textString + "\'";     
        else    
            textString = textString + text ;
    }
    var pwd = document.forms[0].password.value;
    var pwdlen = pwd.length;
    if(pwdlen<15)
    {
        document.forms[0].password.value = textString;
    }
}
```

Try this one and let us know the result ...

Comment: I created the div using document.createElement then i assigned an id to it as div.id="popup" now i want the key which i am pressing should display at the div using javascript only

Comment: i cant give you the code but can explai you what i want to do i want my characters on keypress should be displayed on the div,right now i created one alert(targ.childNodes[0].textContent); with the help of this iam seeing the entered characters on the alertbox ,i want to display it in the div??

Comment: Inthe div part do u have any text field or want to display the text as label?  <div id="othr"  style="display:inline"><html:password styleClass="fieldText" size="30" property="password"/>
</div>